# Retrieving value using xpath in SoapUI Groovy step

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need that the output of an operation **GET ISM** is transferred to the input of another operation SET ESM.

I want to recuperate talon=**603090100042390** in this tag (this is response of GET ISM):

```
<privateUserId>603090100042390@xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</privateUserId>
```

I use this script:

```
groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("GET ISM#Response")
privateUserId = holder.getNodeValue( "//privateUserId" )
assert privateUserId != null
assert privateUserId.length() > 0
latlonNode = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(privateUserId)
latlon = latlonNode.getNodeValue("//privateUserId")
log.info(latlon)
assert latlon != null
context["latlon"] = latlon
```

talon is input for SET ESM.

I have this Error :

> Assertion failed: assert privateUserId != null | | null false Assertion failed: assert privateUserId != null | | null false error at line: 4

but i don't know why the problem in line 4.

I want to fixed this problem. Thank's

Comment: HICHEM, can you please check the answer to see if that helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it is not clear if there any namespaces in the response. Possibly that could be one of the reason to get null.

You could use `Script Assertion` for the first step.

```
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'
def pId = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response).'**'.find{it.name() == 'privateUserId'}.text()

log.info "privateUserId value : $pId"
assert pId, "Value of privateUserId is empty or null"

def userId = pId?.substring(0, pId?.indexOf('@'))
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('USERID', userId)
```

In the next step, wherever extracted user id is needed, use `${#TestCase#USERID}`

Comment: By the way, you won't need any additional groovy script step.

Comment: Hello Rao,  i use Script Assertion not Groovy Script ?

Comment: [Script Assertion] startup failed:
Script4.groovy: 2: unexpected token: } @ line 2, column 94.
   d(it.name() == 'privateUserId'}.text()
                                 ^

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unexpected token: } @ line 2, column 94.

Comment: @HICHEM, i just fixed the issue, there was `)` missing in the second last line i.e., in line 7. Try the updated one please. By the way, you need to update the question instead of adding new answers.

Comment: @HICHEM, there is also change in the line. Please retry the updated answer.

Comment: assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'
def pId = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response).'**'.find(it.name() == 'privateUserId'}.text()

log.info "privateUserId value : $pId"
assert pId, "Value of privateUserId is empty or null"

def userId = pId?.substring(0, pId?.indexOf('@'))
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('USERID', userId)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152503/discussion-between-rao-and-hichem).

Comment: For this Script Assertion : i have this error :[Script Assertion] startup failed:
Script6.groovy: 2: unexpected token: } @ line 2, column 94.
   d(it.name() == 'privateUserId'}.text()
                                 ^